# Select2 Could not bind event on clicking custom no results text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I use select2 and initialize it but it seems like I can't bind an event to it.

Here the html markup

```
<div class="form-group customer-select">
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                            <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
                            <option>Alaska</option>
                            <option>California</option>
                            <option>Delaware</option>
                            <option>Tennessee</option>
                            <option>Texas</option>
                            <option>Washington</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

First attempt.

```
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2({
            "language": {
                "noResults": function(searchedTerm){
                    return "<a href='#' onclick='return showNewCustomerModalForm()' class='add-new-customer'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-default' style='cursor: pointer;'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add New</a>";
                }
            },
            "escapeMarkup": function (markup) {
                return markup;
            }
        });

        function showNewCustomerModalForm() {
            alert(1);
        }
```

The problem with that is alert was never shown when i click add new.

Second Attempt.

```
//Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2({
            "language": {
                "noResults": function(searchedTerm){
                    return "<a href='#' class='add-new-customer'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-default' style='cursor: pointer;'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add New</a>";
                }
            },
            "escapeMarkup": function (markup) {
                return markup;
            }
        });


        $('.customer-select').on('click', '.add-new-customer', function () {
            alert(1);
        });
```

Can anyone help me atleast show the alert when clicking add new. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you made a syntax error because code is working well, check your browser's console for errors

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Gurkanat. Already solved it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```js
//Initialize Select2 Elements
$('.select2').select2({
  "language": {
    "noResults": function(searchedTerm) {
      return "<a href='#' class='add-new-customer'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-default' style='cursor: pointer;'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add New</a>";
    }
  },
  "escapeMarkup": function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }
});


$(document).on('click', '.add-new-customer', function() {
  alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group customer-select">
  <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska</option>
    <option>California</option>
    <option>Delaware</option>
    <option>Tennessee</option>
    <option>Texas</option>
    <option>Washington</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That work I just don't understand why my second attempt didn't work :) Thanks a lot @Bharatsing

Comment: In answer I have used `second attempt` code and changed it and make it work.